# Capybara select option not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I've tried numerous ways to try and my capybara test to select an option from this form.

```
    <select id="mapping_midi_controller_id" name="mapping[midi_controller_id]"><option value="17">MIDI Fighter Classic</option>
      <option value="18">MIDI Fighter Pro</option>
      <option value="16">Traktor Control S2</option>
      <option value="15">Traktor Control S4</option>
      <option value="19">VCI-100</option>
      <option value="0">Other ...</option>
    </select>
```

I've tried 
1)`page.select "VCI-100", :from => "mapping_midi_controller_id"`
2)`select "19", :from => "mapping_midi_controller_id"`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ended up being a testing database issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the second command should be:

> select "**VCI-100**", :from => "mapping_midi_controller_id"